# Using ssh as a proxy

Tags: ssh, proxy, remote-access

I work remotely and I don't have access to some resources of my company from my local machine. Those resources can be accessed only from remote virtual machine. It's not very handy and I see two options how to deal with it:

1. Use -X option and run my ide inside remote vm. I've tried this and this approach had very bad performance.
2. Deploy my app to vm and use remote debug. Could be an option, but still not very convenient.

And then I thought may be I could use ssh as a proxy somehow? I run my apps locally and they get access to resources via ssh. Is it possible? If not, are there other options to deal with my problem?

Comment: Didn't your company offer a [VPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network)? That would be the easy-correct solution.

Comment: I use vpn but for some reasons rights of my subnet is restricted.

Comment: Maybe you can use [tunnels with SSH](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding)--- but this depends on the kind of services. I for example use it to tunnel VNC (VNC is normally restricted to the local network); YMMV.

Comment: You should talk to the sysadmin of the company for which you need access.

Comment: @Rmano thanx, I'll try it out.